# Using Sqlite JDBC Driver in a Gradle Java Project

Tags: java, sqlite, gradle, build.gradle, driver

In this tutorial, http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-java/sqlite-jdbc-driver/, about using sqlite with java, it starts by downloading the JDBC driver from the following website, https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/downloads/. After that it then adds the driver to the project using a Maven build system.

I have had a look around and I cannot see what you should if you are using Gradle? What steps should you take before you the code?

I am using the Intellij IDE if this makes any difference.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Sqlite JDBC driver is available in Maven Central Repository: [SQLite JDBC](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.xerial/sqlite-jdbc)

So in Gradle you can add this dependency in your `build.gradle` as follows:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile group:'org.xerial', name:'sqlite-jdbc', version:'3.8.11.2'
}
```

Or in a Maven project in your `pom.xml` file:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.11.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 15):

The Gradle syntax has changed as of version 3.4. So according to new syntax add the following to your build.gradle file:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.30.1'
}
```